# HTTP Error 404: Not Found during hg pull

Tags: version-control, mercurial, http-status-code-404, bitbucket

I'm trying to pull from a repo (hosted @ Bitbucket) and am continuing to get the following error:

> HTTP Error 404: Not Found

I can navigate to the repo with no issues.  I've tried from both TortoiseHG and the command line.  A co-worker is able to access the same repo without a problem, which means it is something in my environment.

Any ideas?

Full Error:

> % hg --repository C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Projects - 2010\MyRepo pull --verbose --update --config ui.merge=internal:fail https://bitbucket.org/dir/MyRepo
>   HTTP Error: 404 (Not Found)
>   [command returned code 255 Tue Aug 21 11:27:40 2012]
>   MyRepo%

Also of note - I can clone the repo with no problems...

Comment: Don't know the system, but maybe you moved the file to a different directory?

Answer (score 0):

How have you setup the repository using `https` or `ssl`?

if `ssl` then:
You must not behind any proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Was a "bad deployment" per BitBucket support.  Not sure how this only affected me (and not my co-worker) but it is working now.